# Options missing from iptable man page

Tags: iptables

I was looking at `iptables` man pages. But I did not find anything about  `--sport` and `--dport`.

- `--sport` is short for `--source-port`
- `--dport` is short for `--destination-port`

Why are those options missing from Ubuntu manpages? I also looked at

```
iptables --help
info iptables
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--source-port` and `-destination-port` (and their short forms) are provided by the `tcp` extension (and some other extensions). Extensions are documented in the [iptables-extensions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html) man page.